# Java installation on OpenSuse

Tags: linux, software-installation, opensuse, java

I have been trying to install a newer version of JRE (version 8 update 111) on my openSUSE 13.1 (x86_64) platform. I extracted the contents of the tar file in the /opt/java/64 folder and then executed the following two commands,

```
 update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/java/64/jre1.8.0_111/bin/java" 1
 update-alternatives --set java /opt/java/64/jre1.8.0_111/bin/java
```

source - https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/java-for-opensuse

I got no errors during the installation. But after following the procedure, when I checked the version of java, it showed me the older version and not the new one which I thought I installed. Also, the software for which I need the new version of java is still not working. I don't know if there is anything wrong with this method. Also I couldn't find any other way to install java on openSUSE. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why openSUSE 13.1 which is out of support ?